# Ways to Remove Unnecessary Spaces?

Tags: spacing, letter, letter-spacing, line-spacing

My code below gets the street address for each gym, but there is an error in the spacing of the output for the hours that the gym is open. Any ideas of where I went wrong?

```
import urlparse

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import Tag
import requests
import time
import csv

sitemap = 'https://www.planetfitness.com/sitemap'
sitemap_content = requests.get(sitemap).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(sitemap_content, 'html.parser')

atags = soup.select('td[class~=club-title] > a[href^="/gyms"]')
links = [atag.get('href') for atag in atags]

with open('gyms.csv', 'w') as gf:
    gymwriter = csv.writer(gf)
    for link in links:
        gymurl = urlparse.urljoin(sitemap, link)
        sitemap_content = requests.get(gymurl).content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(sitemap_content, 'html.parser')
        gymrow = [ gymurl ]

        address_line1 = soup.select('p[class~=address] > span[class~=address-line1]')
        gymrow.append(address_line1[0].text)
        locality = soup.select('p[class~=address] > span[class~=locality]')
        gymrow.append(locality[0].text)
        administrative_area = soup.select('p[class~=address] > span[class~=administrative-area]')
        gymrow.append(administrative_area[0].text)
        postal_code = soup.select('p[class~=address] > span[class~=postal-code]')
        gymrow.append(postal_code[0].text)
        country = soup.select('p[class~=address] > span[class~=country]')
        gymrow.append(country[0].text)

        strongs = soup.select('div > strong')
        for strong in strongs:
            if strong.text == 'Club Hours':
                for sibling in strong.next_siblings:
                    if isinstance(sibling, Tag):
                        hours = sibling.text
                        gymrow.append(hours)
                        break
        print(gymrow)
        gymwriter.writerow(gymrow)
        time.sleep(3)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: are you using python 2.7?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a working code on what you are trying to:

```
>>>res1 = requests.get(urljoin('https://www.planetfitness.com/', link)).content # ie, the one of the url is 'https://www.planetfitness.com/gyms/albertville-al'
>>>soup1 = BeautifulSoup(res1, 'html.parser')

>>>ps = soup1.find('p',class_ = 'address')
>>>ps
<p class="address" itemprop="address" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress"><span class="address-line1" itemprop="streetAddress">5850 US Hwy 431</span><br/>
<span class="locality" itemprop="addressLocality">Albertville</span>, <span class="administrative-area" itemprop="addressRegion">AL</span> <span class="postal-code" itemprop="postalCode">35950</span><br/>
<span class="country" itemprop="addressCountry">United States</span></p>

>>>address1 = [p['itemprop'] for p in ps.findAll('span')]
>>>address1
['streetAddress', 'addressLocality', 'addressRegion', 'postalCode', 'addressCountry']
```

Comment: @Regression1234 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xpIJ_RxaNUs will help :)

Answer (score -1):

This will give you a dict with keys as the itemprop and values as the address item text, I use python3 in colab so I changed some of the imports but the last 4 lines of the loop should get you what you want:

```py
import requests
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


res = requests.get("https://www.planetfitness.com/sitemap").content
soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'html.parser')

tds = soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'club-title'})
links = [td.find('a')['href'] for td in tds]
keywords = ['gyms']

gym_data = []

for link in links:
    if any(keyword in link for keyword in keywords):
        req = urllib.parse.urljoin('https://www.planetfitness.com/', link)
        res = requests.get(req).content
        site = BeautifulSoup(res)
        ps = site.find('p', class_='address')
        address_dict = {p['itemprop']: p.text for p in ps.findAll('span')}
        gym_data.append(address)
```

Output (probably dont need all these keys...:

```py
[{'streetAddress': '5850 US Hwy 431', 'addressLocality': 'Albertville', 'addressRegion': 'AL', 'postalCode': '35950', 'addressCountry': 'United States'}
{'streetAddress': '987 Market Place', 'addressLocality': 'Alexander City', 'addressRegion': 'AL', 'postalCode': '35010', 'addressCountry': 'United States'}
{'streetAddress': '528 W Town Plaza', 'addressLocality': 'Bessemer', 'addressRegion': 'AL', 'postalCode': '35020', 'addressCountry': 'United States'}
{'streetAddress': '4500 Montevallo Rd', 'addressLocality': 'Birmingham', 'addressRegion': 'AL', 'postalCode': '35210', 'addressCountry': 'United States'}
{'streetAddress': '140 Wildwood Pkwy', 'addressLocality': 'Birmingham', 'addressRegion': 'AL', 'postalCode': '35209', 'addressCountry': 'United States'}
{'streetAddress': '168 Inverness Plaza', 'addressLocality': 'Birmingham', 'addressRegion': 'AL', 'postalCode': '35242', 'addressCountry': 'United States'}
{'streetAddress': '9118 Parkway E', 'addressLocality': 'Birmingham', 'addressRegion': 'AL', 'postalCode': '35206', 'addressCountry': 'United States'}
{'streetAddress': '1727 2nd Ave SW', 'addressLocality': 'Cullman', 'addressRegion': 'AL', 'postalCode': '35055', 'addressCountry': 'United States'}
{'streetAddress': '29685 Renaissance Blvd', 'addressLocality': 'Daphne', 'addressRegion': 'AL', 'postalCode': '36526', 'addressCountry': 'United States'}
{'streetAddress': '809 Beltline Road SW Suite B', 'addressLocality': 'Decatur', 'addressRegion': 'AL', 'postalCode': '35601', 'addressCountry': 'United States'}
{'streetAddress': '3121 Ross Clark Circle', 'addressLocality': 'Dothan', 'addressRegion': 'AL', 'postalCode': '36303', 'addressCountry': 'United States'}
{'streetAddress': '913 Rucker Blvd', 'addressLocality': 'Enterprise', 'addressRegion': 'AL', 'postalCode': '36330', 'addressCountry': 'United States'}
...
]
```

Comment: @Regression1234 Please do not tick an answer that does not help you. This can cause problem to future ppl refering the question and the answer

Comment: @Regression1234 did you end up getting your desired output? This does not include the club hours but does give you the addresses

Comment: well everything after `site = BeautifulSoup(res)` should work for you regardless of your python version and that's really the only different part of the script from your original. Python 2.7 has reached end of life btw, so... probably shouldn't be using it for any new projects. I usually use google colab for scraping because it has most of the dependencies preinstalled and its up-to-date and free https://colab.research.google.com/